# Gráficas particulares en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Alguna idea para implementar una gráfica de este estilo en Python. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte de los ejes está claro, me refiero a cómo poner una línea en un gráfico y además una imagen sobre está línea.

```
    $bits = np.array((7,6,5,4,3,2))
     cc = np.array((0.9855,0.9855,0.9855,0.9853,0.9826,0.9155))

     plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
     plt.plot(bits,cc,color='red',marker='o')
     plt.xlabel('Profundidad de bits por pixel', fontsize=30)
     plt.ylabel('cc', fontsize=30)
     plt.grid()$
```

Comment: ¿TIenes un código y sólo te falta agregar la línea? Publica el código; de ahi seguimos.

Comment: Ese sería el código, la idea sería como poner una flecha a cualquier punto y desde ahí colocar una imagen cualquiera pero sobre la misma gráfica que me da python.

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una linea con forma de flecha, Matplotlib tiene la función `plt.arrow()`. Tu código quedaría así:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bits = np.array((7,6,5,4,3,2))
cc = np.array((0.9855,0.9855,0.9855,0.9853,0.9826,0.9155))

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(bits,cc,color='red',marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Profundidad de bits por pixel', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('cc', fontsize=30)
plt.arrow(x=3, y=0.93, dx=1.90, dy=0.052, width = 0.001, head_width = 0.004, head_length=0.1)
plt.grid()
```

**Salida**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los parámetros que he usado son los siguientes:

- `x`: donde comienza la flecha en el eje de las "x"
- `y`: donde comienza la flecha en el eje de las "y"
- `dx`: en la cantidad que aumenta la flecha en el eje de las "x"
- `dy`: en la cantidad que aumenta la flecha en el eje de las "y"
- `width`: el ancho de la flecha
- `head_width`: el ancho de la punta de la flecha
- `head_length`: el largo de la punta de la flecha

Por su puesto tiene más parámetros para modificar y poner la flecha a tu gusto, puedes verlos en la [documentación oficial de matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)